# Will the runnables be automatically removed if using View.postDelayed()

Tags: android

As I know, call `Handler.postDelayed()` repeatedly (call `postDelayed()` in the same runnable again) may cause some instance hold by the thread never get released.

If I add a runnable using `View.postDelayed()`, am I responsible to call `View.removeCallbacks()` to avoid memory leak? Or will the runnable be removed from the queue when the view is "destroyed"?

Answer (score 1):

> Or will the runnable be removed from the queue when the view is
>   "destroyed"?

It is your responsibility. The runnable will hang in the queue until either you remove it explicitly or it is executed (it the runnable is not posting itself in the queue). I would strongly suggest you to call `removeCallbacks`. If you are subclassing View you could use `onDetachedFromWindow()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, onDetachedFromWindow() is great. now I can make some of my code more graceful. I have another question: I write a util class to do some animation to arbitrary view, and calls something like stopAnim() in Activity.onDestroy() to remove the runnables (
"remove it explicitly"). But I think it's a little ugly to let the user of the util class to do the release work explicitly. Is there a way to know when the view is no longer used?

Comment: I find a way but do not know if it is appropriate. in the beginning of Runnable.run(), try get window token use View.getWindowToken(). if null, then exit loop. works for me so far.

Comment: *Is there a way to know when the view is no longer used?* if you are subclassing View you should be using `onDetachedFromWindow()`  to remove/deregister